# Immediately exit a JavaScript function when a specified condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that it just won't return true no matter what I do, I don't know, maybe I'm missing something here.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to compare the value of an input field with the options of a datalist. So far, the function compares the values and returns true once one match is found but it just keeps looping a returns false afterward.

```
function OperatorSelectionCheck() {

                if ($("#ModalEmployeeSelect").val() != "")
                {
                    $('#ModalEmployeeSelectList option').filter(function () {

                        if ($(this).val() === $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").val())
                        {
                            $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").removeClass("tberror");
                            $("#timesheet-modal-errorbag").text("");
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").focus();
                            $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").addClass("tberror");

                            $("#timesheet-modal-errorbag").text("The entry " + $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").val() + " does not match any users in the database." );
                            return false;
                        }

                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").focus();
                    $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").addClass("tberror");
                    $("#timesheet-modal-errorbag").text("Please select an operator.");
                    return false
                }
            }
```

Comment: But you are not returning `true` anywhere in your code, my man. `return;` returns `undefined`. To return `true` you have to `return true;`. On top of that, `.filter()` is a function in and of itself, so return true from that won't return true from `OperatorSelectionCheck`;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe refactoring? I didn't run the code below, but might help you in the right direction.

```
var collection = $('#ModalEmployeeSelectList option').filter(function () {
   return $(this).val() === $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").val()
})

if (collection.length > 0) {
  $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").removeClass("tberror");
  $("#timesheet-modal-errorbag").text("");
}
else {
 $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").focus();
 $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").addClass("tberror");
 $("#timesheet-modal-errorbag").text("The entry " +   $("#ModalEmployeeSelect").val() + " does not match any users in the database." );
}
```